# c# FluentFTP, download only the last folder in the given path

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluentftp

I'd like to download folder with c# [FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/blob/master/FluentFTP.CSharpExamples/DownloadDirectory.cs) library. The folder is downloaded but I'd like to have in my machine only the last folder in the given path.

```
List<FtpResult> res = client.DownloadDirectory(tmpFolder, "play_files\\test_folder\\", FtpFolderSyncMode.Update);
return res;
```

what I get in the local folder is a folder named **play_files** and a subfolder **test_folder**.

what I want to get , is just one folder **test_folder** and I'd like to know if is it possible to rename it or not.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I don't remember it. I gave up working with c# and entity-framework for a year

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the solution.
For remoteFolder, start with '/'.
For example, "/abc/def"not "abc/def".

```cs
client.DownloadDirectory(@"D:\download\", "/download/folder", FtpFolderSyncMode.Update, FtpLocalExists.Overwrite);
```